# Example HtmlUnit Test Failing

Tags: java, maven, junit, htmlunit

I am trying to run the sample HtmlUnit test case via Junit.

My project is Maven based. Do I need to add ALL the depdencies listen under compile and test to my POM? http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html
Right now I have added the htmlunit dependencies, httpconnections and nekohtml.

Sample test:

```
@Test
public void homePage() throws Exception {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME_16);
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");

    assertEquals("HtmlUnit - Welcome to HtmlUnit", page.getTitleText());

    final String pageAsXml = page.asXml();
    assertTrue(pageAsXml.contains("<body class=\"composite\">"));

    final String pageAsText = page.asText();
    assertTrue(pageAsText.contains("Support for the HTTP and HTTPS protocols"));

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

The tests fail w the following errors:

```
homePage(ActiveComponentTest)  Time elapsed: 2.06 sec  <<< ERROR!
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ObjectInstantiationException: unable to create HTML parser
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.<init>(HTMLParser.java:427)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.<init>(HTMLParser.java:351)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:205)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:180)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:267)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:155)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:440)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:315)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:380)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:365)
    at ActiveComponentTest.homePage(ActiveComponentTest.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://cyberneko.org/html/features/scanner/allow-selfclosing-iframe' is not recognized.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setFeature(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.<init>(HTMLParser.java:420)
    ... 43 more
homePage(ActiveComponentTest)  Time elapsed: 2.064 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: No document element (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1190)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.isOnbeforeunloadAccepted(HtmlPage.java:2123)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.TopLevelWindow.close(TopLevelWindow.java:112)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.closeAllWindows(WebClient.java:1916)
    at ActiveComponentTest.tearDown(ActiveComponentTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:36)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
```

Comment: I don't think the error you're getting has anything to do with dependencies declared in your `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue turned out to me one of my project dependencies in my POM was pulling in a different, and incompatible, version of nekoHTML.

Once I removed the offending dependency (which was a hold over from the project im testing, not the this project which i used to test the other proj -- long story) everything worked just fine.

Comment: Yes, same error is resolved by removing old version of nekoHTML. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@jlars62, you probably have something like this in your pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add the exclusion as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
        **<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
                <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>**
    </dependency>
```