# Unable to create HTML parser when using WebDriver

Tags: eclipse, macos, selenium, webdriver

Following this WebDriver tutorial: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted
on osx, eclipse, selenium 2.33, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ObjectInstantiationException: unable to create HTML parser
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:32:38'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.3', java.version: '1.6.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:376)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:184)
    at com.dexter.test.exactor.command.GoogleWDCommand.execute(GoogleWDCommand.java:21)
    at com.dexter.test.exactor.command.GoogleWDCommand.main(GoogleWDCommand.java:13)
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ObjectInstantiationException: unable to create HTML parser
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.<init>(HTMLParser.java:454)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.<init>(HTMLParser.java:378)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:212)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:434)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:366)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://cyberneko.org/html/features/parse-noscript-content' is not recognized.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setFeature(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.<init>(HTMLParser.java:446)
    ... 15 more
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Are you navigating to "http://cyberneko.org/html/features/parse-noscript-content"? Does it work when you navigate to http://www.google.com?

Comment: SO stripped my http:// in the urls above. Make sure you have that in your url that webdriver is navigating to.

Comment: Have you added all the jars of the selenium you downloaded? You have to add all the jars inside and outside the libs folder.

Comment: @cegprakash I have added the selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar to the classpath.  That's all. What else I need?

Comment: One jar file is not enough because, a jar file may depend on other jar files and so on.. Download this and add all the jars in and out of the libs folder. http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-java-2.33.0.zip.

Comment: @cegprakash Added all of them. didn't work. Same error

Comment: The error says "unable to create HTML parser". Can you provide the url or the source of the page you are trying to access? check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869817/example-htmlunit-test-failing

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to add a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet.
I noticed in many other forums that this problem may be related to the version of your *nekohtml* dependency version. Have you checked that already?

I don't even know if you already fixed it since this post is almost one year old.