# Extracting necessary url from a set of url

Tags: java, arraylist, jsoup

I copied the same code and tried executing but it shows the following exceptions.Please check this. Are you getting the same exceptions.If not please provide the HtmlUnit API's link to make sure that I tried the same thing.

```
 public class Program{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, IOException {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
        WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("http://www.firstpost.com/tag/crime-in-india"));
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        List<HtmlAnchor> anchors1 = page.getAnchors();
        HtmlAnchor link2 = null;
        for (HtmlAnchor anchor : anchors1) {
            if (anchor.asText().indexOf("Why do we care more when NRIs go missing?") > -1) {
                link2 = anchor;
                break;
            }
        }
        page = link2.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        DomNodeList<DomElement> paras = page.getElementsByTagName("p");
        for (DomElement el : paras.toArray(new DomElement[paras.size()])) {
            System.out.println(el.asText());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `Jsoup` and `HtmlUnit` for your purpose. `HtmlUnit` would help in case you want to dynamically 'click' those links and scrape the content of the resulting page. You can accumulate the text of those anchor tags to iterate over all of them, `Jsoup` would also help in accumulating the text of those hyperlinks which can be used by `HtmlUnit` later - but at a cost of 2 connections.

Below is a code sample of scraping the data from one of those hyperlinks from your site url, notice I give your base url and then check for a specific link to get its contents - you can select a specific set of links on your page depending on a pattern.

It traverses to you link, clicks it and retrieves the specific set of data you are looking for.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
            throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, IOException {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);

        WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL(
                "http://www.firstpost.com/tag/crime-in-india"));

        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        List<HtmlAnchor> anchors1 = page.getAnchors();
        HtmlAnchor link2 = null;

        for (HtmlAnchor anchor : anchors1) {
            if (anchor.asText().indexOf(
                    "Why do we care more when NRIs go missing?") > -1) {
                link2 = anchor;
                break;
            }
        }
        page = link2.click();

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        DomNodeList<DomElement> paras = page.getElementsByTagName("p");
        for (DomElement el : paras.toArray(new DomElement[paras.size()])) {
            System.out.println(el.asText());
        }
    }
```

**Prints the news article contents:**

[image]

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ObjectInstantiationException: unable to create HTML parser
 at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.<init>(HTMLParser.java:455)
 at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.<init>(HTMLParser.java:379)
 at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:213)
 at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)

Comment: there might be a conflict, check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869817/example-htmlunit-test-failing) helps?

Comment: @chopzz I have linked to a question where a similar error is encountered. I have given the working details in the answer above

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will be page specific as all the pages have a different structure. How many websites do you want to get data from ? if it is only 5 or 6 then you may want to code for each one of them individually.

Comment: how can I get those needed links?how can the code be modified?